# How do I determine via Windows command line whether ALBD service is running?

Tags: windows, clearcase

OK, I know how to start and stop ALBD, but how do I determine whether it is currently running?
This is something I want to put in a Perl or DOS script, so it would have to be a non-GUI solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this technote "[Start and stop ClearCase from the Windows command line](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21134178)", and note that **`albd` isn't the only service you should be checking**.
And if you have trouble starting albd on Windows, see "[Troubleshooting ALBD startup failures on Windows](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21177467)".

CLEARCASE

> The ClearCase server processes (Location Broker, Lock Manager, and Credentials Manager services) can be started and stopped from the command line; however, the MVFS is loaded directly into the kernel and cannot be shut down from the command line.
>
> To reload the MVFS, restart the host; see technote 1230196 for more details About the MultiVersion File System (MVFS).
>
> Run the following command to see ClearCase ALBD, Lock Manager, and Credentials Manager services are running on the host:

```
>NET START
```

> A list of programs will scroll on the screen, and you want to look for a derivative of the following entries:

```
Atria Location Broker
IBM Rational Lock Manager
Rational Cred Manager
```

> To start/stop the `ALBD`, `LOCKMGR`, and `CCCREDMGR` services, issue the following commands:

```
NET START(or STOP) ALBD
NET START(or STOP) LOCKMGR
NET START(or STOP) CCCREDMGR
```

---

Note those net start commands might require **administrative privileges**:
See [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=360461):

> We have non-administrator CC users. So they can start and stop CC, when they have CC installed as admin we also run some commands the change the CC services to allow non-admins to start and stop them. Here are the commands out of the bat file that makes the service changes. Once upon a time I understood what the service_opts string did.

```
@ECHO.
@ECHO Purpose: Configure ClearCase Services for non-Admin rights management

set service_opts="D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)"

@ECHO.
@ECHO ++ Processing ALBD service
SC SDSET Albd %service_opts%
SC config Albd start= demand
@ECHO.
@ECHO ++ Processing Credentials Manager service
SC SDSET cccredmgr %service_opts%
SC config cccredmgr start= demand
@ECHO.
@ECHO ++ Processing Lock Manager service
SC SDSET LockMgr %service_opts%
SC config LockMgr start= demand

@ECHO.
@ECHO ++ Processing MVFS service
SC SDSET mvfs %service_opts%
SC config mvfs start= auto

@ECHO.
@ECHO The following ClearCase services:
@ECHO ALBD
@ECHO Cred Manager (CCCREDMGR)
@ECHO Lock Manager (LockMGR)
@ECHO MVFS
@ECHO have been configured to allow non-Administrator privilege users
@ECHO to start and stop these services
@ECHO.
@ECHO You must reboot this PC before attempting to start or
@ECHO stop the ClearCase services without being an Administrator
@ECHO.
@PAUSE
```

---

As [the OP uhclem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225101/uhclem) comments, the `SDSET Albd %service_opts%` part is explained in Microsoft tech note "[ee](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374928.aspx)":

> The [security descriptor definition language (`SDDL`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379567.aspx) uses `ACE` strings in the `DACL` and `SACL` components of a [security descriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721625.aspx#_security_security_descriptor_gly) string.
>
> As shown in the [Security Descriptor String Format examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379570.aspx), each `ACE` in a security descriptor string is enclosed in parentheses. The fields of the `ACE` are in the following order and are separated by semicolons (`;`).
>
> Note: There are alternate formats for [access control entries (`ACEs`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721532.aspx#_security_access_control_entry_gly) and conditional `ACEs`.
> For conditional `ACEs`, see [Security Descriptor Definition Language for Conditional `ACEs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981030.aspx).

```
ace_type;ace_flags;rights;object_guid;inherit_object_guid;account_sid; resource_attribute
```

Comment: Extremely informative. Thank you. This even addresses provision of the capability for non-admin users to start/stop these services, which is the ultimate goal.

Comment: I just tested out the above batch script for granting CC privileges to non-admins, and it worked like a charm! I wanted to understand what SDSET was doing with the cryptic service_opts string, and found my answer at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374928.aspx

Comment: @UhClem good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Albd is running as a normal windows service. To check if it is already started:

```
net start | find "Atria Location Broker"
```

To start the service

```
net start Albd
```

To stop the service

```
net start Albd
```

See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/327336/net-start-service-how-where-to-get-the-service-name).