# ClearCase db_server.exe: Error: db_VISTA error -920 (errno == "Bad file descriptor")

Tags: clearcase, ibm-rational

Seeing following errors in the server db log.

db_server.exe(): Error: db_VISTA error -920 (errno == "Bad file descriptor")
db_server.exe(): Error: Cannot open database in ".vbs\db"

Any idea, seeing this error for every 20 mins. This is happening for only two vobs.

Followed below with no luck.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21236027

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21148639

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21133944

Comment: What version of ClearCase are you running? What OS your server is using?

Comment: Windows 2003 and 7.1.0.2

Comment: Ok, I maintain my answer: stop everything, raise the parameters in the vob_almd_params of your two vobs and restart everything.

Comment: @VonC, thanks a lot, will give a try and reply.

Answer (score 1):

The [About db_VISTA errors](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21248861) page mentions:

```
db_VISTA database error -920 - no lock manager is installed
db_VISTA error 2 from OpenFileMapping() of lockmgr_almd
```

And reference the technote "[DB_Vista -920 error and Error 2 from `OpenFileMapping()`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21157857)"

Even if this isn't exactly the same error message, check the status of your lock manager (`lockmgr.exe` on Windows, `lockmgr` on Unix), both on the client and the server.

Regarding the [`db_server` process](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc%2Ftopics%2Fr_intro_serverprocs_db.htm), you can try a stop/restart ClearCase on the server, to reset both db_server and [`vob_server` processes](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc%2Ftopics%2Fr_intro_serverprocs_vob.htm).

That can be also related to almd parameters, initially found in:

```
 /opt/rational/clearcase/config/vob/db/vob_almd_params
```

(for all vobs), but also found in each vobs:

```
 /path/to/vobstorage/yourVob.vbs/db/vob_almd_params
```

I usually try to raise those parameters in case of 920 errors.
For instance:

```
-u 4000 -q 16000
```

That (meaning those local vob configs) would explain why you see errors in only two of your vobs.

To stop the services on Windows: "[How do I determine via Windows command line whether ALBD service is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9390423/6309)".

Comment: ,weird, I don't find vob_almd_params under db and config folder.

Comment: @maestromani that might have changed on Windows (all my vobs servers were Unix only). Do a search for any `vob_*param*.*` file

Comment: I see -u 4000 and -q 16000 in the regedit. suddenly I see db_server.exe(14424): Error: db_VISTA error -917 (errno == "Bad file descriptor") and db_server.exe(14424): Error: DBMS error in "\atria\lib\db\db1.c" line 1287coming up. Any idea ?

Comment: @maestromani I don't understand your last comment. do you mean you have modified something in the registry of the windows server? If yes, which entry? Did you restart everything?

Comment: I looked at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\Lock
and see -a almd -f 980 -u 4000 -q 16000 as value already. So didn't not change anything.

Comment: @maestromani can you at least restart everything, and see if the errors persists?

Comment: @maestromani also try and double the first two value, if the error persists: `-a almd -f 1960 -u 8000 -q 16000`

Comment: Service restarted twice, Error: DBMS error in "\atria\lib\db\db1.c" line 1287 seen for few mins, then back to old error.

Comment: @maestromani did you restart *all* services? And do you see an 907 error (which exists: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21236027), or a 917 one? (which does not exist or at least, isn't documented)

Comment: All services restarted. I confirm I see 917. --> db_server.exe(14424): Error: db_VISTA error -917 (errno == "Bad file descriptor")

Comment: @maestromani never seen a 917. Time to dbcheck the vob, I guess. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21122748

Comment: @maestromani just to be sure: is your client using a ClearCase 7.1.0.2, like the server does?

Comment: Yes, I will do dbcheck later today. Most of the clients got 7.1.2.10. This case is there for almost a year now.917 error is only for few mins, now back to 920

Comment: @maestromani you mean clients are running a more recent version than the ClearCase running on the server?

Comment: Not sure the rational behind this, this is the case before I came into this organization. This is there for almost a year now. I'm seeing all this happening in last two days. to my knowledge nothing changed in the servers.

Comment: @maestromani How many vobs are you managing on the Windows Vob server? Maybe those values are actually too important? for instance: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/perf-svr.htm mention 18 as a starting value for the -f parameter ( number of database files that can be open concurrently): you have 980! That seems quite ambituous for a *Windows* server.

Comment: weird didn't receive alert for last comment. We have 116 vobs in our environment.

Comment: @maestromani still, 1960 seem too important for that server. Try reading https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/perf-svr.htm and adjust your parameters.

Comment: I'm now, I see one service account using clearcase license every 30 mins, is there any way to find what it is doing with clearcase ? I see this errors hitting every 30 mins.