# Clearcase on new Windows Domain

Tags: windows-7, clearcase, clearcase-automation

We have migrated our Windows user PCs to new Domain.

For each clearcase user, We need to do below work manually.

```
1. Albd service account and password to be changed in Service window category.
2. In Registry domain name need to be changed.
3. Old domain snapshot views needs to be find and  unregistred.
4. Again same snapshot views need to be registered for New hostname.
5.Fix_Prot needs to be run to change snapshot views owner and group name.
```

So for this do we have any utility/tool?Kindly advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native utility, but it can be scripted, and executed (provided the user can launch that script as Administrator, in order to have access to regedit and other admin tools)

For changing the albs service account in the Windows service, you [would use `sc`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) (after stopping the service with net stop): see "[How do I determine via Windows command line whether ALBD service is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9390423/6309)"

And here is an [example for `fix_prot`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46478530/6309) using aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely to need to remove and recreate the views. Fix_prot may remove the view's additional group information, which will cause frustratingly intermittent issues accessing elements not owned by the view's primary group.

Fix_prot only coincidentally works on views. Its real purpose is to make it so you can register and tag a VOB, and then use protectvob to put the rest of the groups back.

There is no tool to restore view additional groups.

If you're going through with fix_prot on the views, you'll need to do it as step 4 and not 5 as the view won't register unless you at least do a fix_prot to replace the CC admin group.